# ponydebuggerのインストールでこける

Tags: ios, xcode

お世話になります

ponydebuggerをインストールしたく下記のサイトを参考にやっておりますが、うまくいかず、困っております

http://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/d0c42a988010e1504f1c

最終的に以下のエラーを吐いてこけています

```
New python executable in    /Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/bin/python
Installing setuptools..............done.
Installing pip..............done.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site- packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 314, in run
isolated=options.isolated_mode,
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 104, in    from_editable
   isolated=isolated)
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 54, in __init__
  req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2873, in parse
   reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2820, in parse_requirements
"version spec")
  File "/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2785, in scan_list
  raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
  ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'ponydebugger --allow-external   pybonjour --allow-unverified pybonjour', 'at', ' --allow-external pybonjour --allow-unverified pybonjour')

  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 2464, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 946, in main
   File "<stdin>", line 1796, in after_install
   File    "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
   raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/shiratsu/Library/PonyDebugger/bin/pip', 'install', '-U', '-e', 'git+https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git#egg=ponydebugger --allow-external pybonjour --allow-unverified pybonjour']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

ここも調べてるのですが、どうも自分のパターンと違うようでうまくいきません
https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger/issues/100

今現在以下のエラーから抜け出せません。

```
pip install -U -e git+https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git#egg=ponydebugger --allow-external pybonjour --allow-unverified pybonjour
zsh: no matches found: git+https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git#egg=ponydebugger
```

どなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `git+https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git#egg=ponydebugger` をシングルクォートで囲むとどうなりますか？ もしくは、`setopt nonomatch` を実行してからインストールして見てください。

Comment: うまくいきました！ありがとうございます

Comment: うまくいって良かったです。ところで、このサイトでは質問をされた方がご自身で問題を解決された場合には、自分で回答を記入する決まりになっています（強制ではないです）。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 了解です。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決しました
やったことは、シングルクォーテションをつけただけ。。。。
ありがとうございます

```
pip install -U -e  'git+https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git#egg=ponydebugger' --allow-  external pybonjour --allow-unverified pybonjour
Obtaining ponydebugger from   git+https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git#egg=ponydebugger
  Cloning https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger.git to ./src/ponydebugger
Collecting tornado (from ponydebugger)
  Using cached tornado-4.1.tar.gz
Collecting pybonjour (from ponydebugger)
  pybonjour is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
  Downloading http://pybonjour.googlecode.com/files/pybonjour-1.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting certifi (from tornado->ponydebugger)
   Downloading certifi-14.05.14.tar.gz (168kB)
   100% |################################| 172kB 1.4MB/s
   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.0.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py:283: UserWarning: The version specified    requires normalization, consider using '14.5.14' instead of '14.05.14'.
 Collecting backports.ssl-match-hostname (from tornado->ponydebugger)
 Downloading backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2.tar.gz
 Installing collected packages: backports.ssl-match-hostname, certifi,  pybonjour, tornado, ponydebugger
  Running setup.py install for backports.ssl-match-hostname
  Running setup.py install for certifi
   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.0.5- py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py:283: UserWarning: The version specified   requires normalization, consider using '14.5.14' instead of '14.05.14'.
   Running setup.py install for pybonjour
   Running setup.py install for tornado
     building 'tornado.speedups' extension
     clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c tornado/speedups.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/tornado/speedups.o
     clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/tornado/speedups.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/tornado/speedups.so
   Running setup.py develop for ponydebugger
     Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ponyd.egg-link (link to .)
   Adding ponyd 1.0 to easy-install.pth file
   Installing ponyd script to /usr/local/bin
   Installed /Users/shiratsu/src/ponydebugger
  Successfully installed backports.ssl-match-hostname-3.4.0.2 certifi-14.5.14 ponydebugger pybonjour-1.1.1 tornado-4.1
```

Comment: 本質問が解決済みであることを示すために、ご自身の回答を承認して頂ければと思います。

Comment: すっかり忘れてました。失礼いたしました。。。

Comment: いえいえ、対応ありがとうございます。